# Error initializing GroovyPageView

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am using `grails 2.3.4`. When I load my index.gsp page I get:

```
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/testApplication
| Application loaded in interactive mode. Type 'stop-app' to shutdown.
| Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion:
....[/testApplication].[gsp] Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context w
ith path [/testApplication] threw exception
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Error map
ping onto view [/index]: Error initializing GroovyPageView
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing GroovyPageView
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException:
Expecting '=' after attribute name (ng-app).
        ... 3 more
[/testApplication].[gsp] Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with
path [/testApplication] threw exception
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Error map
ping onto view [/index]: Error initializing GroovyPageView
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing GroovyPageView
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException:
Expecting '=' after attribute name (ng-app).
        ... 3 more
[/testApplication].[gsp] Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with
path [/testApplication] threw exception
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Error map
ping onto view [/index]: Error initializing GroovyPageView
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing GroovyPageView
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException:
Expecting '=' after attribute name (ng-app).
        ... 3 more
```

My `index.gsp` looks simple:

```
<head ng-app> 
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>Title Page</title>

<!-- here we are loading angularjs -->
<r:require module="angular" />

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>Hello World!</div>
        <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>
        <p>1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

and my `URL mapping` looks like that:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/api/product"(resources:"product")
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')

    }
}
```

Why do I get this error?
I really appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

My `ApplicationResources.groovy` file:

```
modules = {

    'angular' {
        resource url:'/js/lib/angular-1.2.8/angular.min.js'
        resource url:'/js/lib/angular-1.2.8/angular-resource.min.js'
        println "Loading libs"
    }

}
```

Thats my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Check is angular.js loaded correctly. I guess there are some problem with js loading.

Comment: @emilan How to check this?

Comment: If you are using chrome, just hit F12 and navigate to 'Network' tab, refresh the page, and you can see angular.js file, if it loads correctly.

Comment: do you have angular module defined in ApplicationResources.groovy ?
is it correct ?

Comment: and put the content of the ApplicationResources file in your question

Comment: Can't see angular file in your folder structure.

Comment: @emilan What do you mean?

Comment: is this correct path '/js/lib/angular-1.2.8/angular.min.js' ?

Comment: Tried this also out, but it delivers the same result as before...

Comment: put script directly into your index.gsp, don't use resource plugin.

Comment: @emilan Could you provide an example on how to do that?

Comment: btw checkt out chrome and angular does not get loaded...

Comment: here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/fDFf4/

Comment: and here is your example: http://jsfiddle.net/fDFf4/1/

Comment: thx besides loading via CDN is it also possible to load it via the js folder?

Comment: sure: <script src=""${resource(dir: 'js/lib', file: 'file.js')}"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in exception
**Expecting '=' after attribute name (ng-app)**.
Why you put "**ng-app**" in "head" tag ?
try to remove it.

Comment: Thx for your answer! However putting it into my `<div>` does not use angularjs. I just get plain `html output` which is not rendered by `angularjs`.

Comment: try to put ng-app to your html tag.
<html ng-app>
  <head>