# Angularjs with Grails <content> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, sitemesh

I'm using Grails [Sitemesh Content Blocks](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.1/guide/theWebLayer.html#sitemeshContentBlocks) for page decoration with **Grails 2.2.2**

The problem is **Angular** is not recognizing the HTML `<content>` tag provided by sitemesh so every variable I want to display in that tag are not displaying.

**For example**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

    <span>{{some.variable}}</span>// works

    <content>
        <span>{{some.variable}}</span>// DONT WORKS!! (not displaying)
    </content>

</div>
```

Is there a way to tell angular to recognize the `<content>` tag ?
Or anything I should do to make it work.

Thank you

Comment: maybe same issue as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481780/error-initializing-groovypageview?noredirect=1#comment32424270_21481780

Comment: I have no errors.. I don't think this is the same issue..

Comment: Try to remove Angular specific code, I think the problem is not connected with Angular. Just test it without angular.

Comment: what you mean? I dont understand... without angular sure there is no problem :)

Comment: Nobody can give me some tips.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your source page to see if the content tag is still there.  If it is not then it has nothing to do with angular but probably with sitemesh.  I believe under Grails the content tag needs an attribute tag which is then recalled in the g:propertyPage taglib to render its content